# How to use break command in idb(intel compiler debugger) for fortran executable file?

Tags: debugging, gdb, fortran, intel, gfortran

I am new to the idb/gdb debugger so I am apologize for the bad questions in advance. I am trying to set a breakpoint in a function called set_time_i which is in a file called time_manager.F90 by using idb. However, idb keeps giving me error message and stops me from setting hte breakpoint. May I know if I did something wrong ? I tried all these commands:

1) (idb) break time_manager.F90:set_time_i

2) (idb) break time_manager:set_time_i

3) (idb) break set_time_i

4) (idb) break time_manager_:set_time_i_

The error message is

" break time_manager:set_time_i ^ Unable to parse input as legal command or Fortran expression."

None of above work. Did I miss something when I use it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike C, the command

```
break file:function
```

doesn't work for Fortran (be it GDB or IDB). I generally start Intel debugger in GDB mode and the 3rd form of your invocation works.

```
[shell] $ idbc -gdb a.out   # Command-line, GDB mode 
(idb) break  set_time_i
```

Comment: Too bad I do not have idbc. My error message showed is " time_manager_mod::set_time_i(...)...etc" So I even tried " break time_manager_mod::set_time_i". It still can not work. So strange~

Comment: idbc is a console version of IDB. It is installed alongside idb, by default.

Comment: Hi Thanks for help. I have tried to use nm command to find symbol from object files. Then, I use break command on the object symbol and it worked. I guess not all debugger support function name debugging.